# Relative import with Python 3 from folder containing a dot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Say I have the following structure:

```
main.py
.folder/
    a.py
    b.py
```

and using Python 3 and being currently in `main.py` I want to `import *` from `a.py`.

- I assume `from .folder.a import *` is wrong as that ignores that the folder is actually named `.folder`, not `folder`
- I assume `from ..folder.a import *` is wrong as I'm not targeting a relative parent directory called `folder`, but a folder named `.folder` within the same directory as `main.py`

Comment: does your `.folder` directory has a `__init__.py` file in it?

Comment: Module starting with dot is seen as a relative import. https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/importlib/__init__.py#l117

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this; names of packages and modules need to be valid Python identifiers, which `.folder` is not. You should rename your directory.

Comment: Does @vasili-syrakis 's comment above reference your answer, @daniel-roseman?